# Selecting specific lines in spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a massive spreadsheet that I need to select certain rows of data out of and the rest can be deleted. All of the rows I want to select begin with RC followed by 6 numbers. The numbers can be different so they will look like RC125468 and RC212548. There are blank rows in the spreadsheet, but I don't know if that will make a difference. To cover all of the rows that are in the spreadsheet I would have to cycle through about 30000.

Here is my code (it's bad, it's mostly from things I found on Google that I thought would work):

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A2:A35000")
    Set x = x + 1
    Do Until x = 30000
        If Range(x, 1).Value <> ("RC??????") Then
            Delete.Row (x)
       End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

I've tried a couple of different things, but keep running into different errors and can't put something together that will even run let alone select the info that I need. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show some sample data and what you expect to get removed and what should stay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim i as Long
For i = 30000 to 1 step -1
    If Not ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i) Like "*RC*" Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next I
```

Comment: I picked on BruceWayne for using `Integer` instead of `Long` for the type of `i`, so I had better be fair and suggest you change it too.  (The OP says that they will have "about 30000" rows, so there is a good chance that they will get to the situation where they have more than 32767 rows, at which point trying to use an `Integer` will cause an overflow error.)  +1 on the assumption that you will change it once you read this comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub Macro2()
Dim x       As Long
For x = 30000 To 1 Step -1
    If Left(Cells(x, 1).Value, 2) <> "RC" Or Not IsNumeric(Right(Cells(x,1).Value),6) Then
        Rows(x).Delete
    End If
Next x
End Sub
```

If a cell does not start with RC, or if it does, if the 6 end digits aren't numeric, it deletes the row.

Comment: (a) `Integer`? Perhaps `Long` - 30000 is getting close to an overflow for an `Integer`  (b) `And`? Definitely `Or`.  (c) `Rows(x).EntireRow`? Perhaps `Rows(x)` - `EntireRow` is superfluous if you are referring to a row.  (d) Today is a "pick on Bruce" day :D

Comment: @YowE3K - (a) Good point, will edit. (b) (long day), I want to make sure the left 2 values are RC and the last 6 are numeric and delete that Row. Doesn't that do that? `RC123456` gets kept, but `RC12345a` gets kept.
  (c) Hm, good point. I'm in the habit of being too explicit I think, (d)[...sigh](https://i.imgur.com/giOWffI.gif)

Comment: (b) Consider `"XY123456"` - It doesn't start with `"RC"` but the last 6 characters are numeric.  So you will have `If True And Not True Then` --> `If  True And False Then` --> `If False Then` --> nothing gets deleted.

Comment: @YowE3K - Ahh, yes, I see. Good call.

Comment: **Now** you can have your +1 :D

Comment: `RC1234567` would also pass your test, as would `RCX123456`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld yeah I thought about adding a `Len()` test. I'll wait for more info from op before adding more tests/stuff

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```
Sub Macro1()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A2:A35000")
    For x = 1 To 30
        If Not Cells(x, 1).Value Like "RC*" Then
            Rows(x).EntireRow.Delete
            x = x - 1
       End If
    Next x
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This will delete any line where the first cell does not start RC

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

My first try would be using the Advanced Filter. When using the `Advanced Filter`, invoked through VBA, it is possible to copy the filtered range to a different worksheet (unlike doing this in Excel).  So you could try:

```
Option Explicit
Sub SpecialFilter()
    Dim myTable As Range
    Dim myCriteria As Range
    Dim vResults As Variant
    Dim WS As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range

    Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long

Set wsRes = Worksheets("sheet1")
Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 1)

Set WS = Worksheets("sheet2")
With WS
    LastRow = .Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, searchorder:=xlByRows, _
                            searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    LastCol = .Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, searchorder:=xlByColumns, _
                            searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column

    Set myTable = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol))

    Set myCriteria = .Range(.Cells(1, LastCol + 5), .Cells(2, LastCol + 5))
End With

myCriteria(2).Formula = "=AND(LEFT(" & myTable(2, 1).Address(rowabsolute:=False) & _
    ",2)=""RC"", ISNUMBER(-MID(" & myTable(2, 1).Address(rowabsolute:=False) & _
    ",3,6)),LEN(" & myTable(2, 1).Address(rowabsolute:=False) & ")=8)"

wsRes.Cells.Clear

myTable.AdvancedFilter _
            Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
            criteriarange:=myCriteria, _
            copytorange:=rRes

myCriteria.Clear

End Sub
```

---

However, using your approach of cycling through each line, you need to make a few changes

- Use the proper syntax to test for RC followed by 6 digits `"RC######"`
- Delete from bottom to top.  Going from top to bottom confuses the index pointer.

Your code with the modifications:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Macro1()
    Dim x As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long

'Determine last row in column A
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Cycle from last row to first
'Assume row 1 is a column header not to be deleted

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

For x = LastRow To 2 Step -1
    If Not Cells(x, 1) Like "RC######" Then Rows(x).Delete
Next x

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Try both and see which works better.

Other notes:

- In VBA, there is no good reason to use the `Integer` data type unless you want to throw an overflow error for numbers out of its range.
- It is probably more efficient to actually determine the last row (and last column if necessary) of a range than oversizing it.

  - you could use the `currentregion` property, but with blank rows, it will not be reliable.  The methods I showed should both be reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Build a range then delete in one go as opposed to deleting 1 row at a time:

```
Sub DeleteByCriteria()
Dim MyRange As Range, Cell As Object
For Each Cell In Range("A2:A35000")
    If Left(Cell.Value, 2) = "RC" Then
        If MyRange Is Nothing Then
            Set MyRange = Range(Cell.Address)
        Else
            Set MyRange = Union(MyRange, Range(Cell.Address))
        End If
    End If
Next
MyRange.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

If you really want to go 1 at a time then do it in reverse with something like:

```
For X = 30000 to 1 step -1
```

This way you don't need to minus 1 from X every time you delete a row.